# Read lines until a particular line occurs

Tags: python, text-files, readline

I have two test files. File1 - A number of titles, File 2 -  Titles and the description. 
I need to read one line from File 1 , ie a title and find the matching title in File 2 and print the description until a line 'END'
I tried using islice and f.next() but does not work

```
with open('H:/Python/proj1/p4 faults.swi', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.readlines()

    for x in ViolList:
         for i, line in enumerate(content):
            line =line.upper()
            x1 = x1.upper()

            if x1 in line :
                count = count + 1

                outFile.write(line)
                outFile.write(content_file.next())
                if line.strip()== 'End':
                    break
```

Comment: what are `ViolList` and `x1`? Do you get an error? Can you show an example section of your input file?

Comment: ViolList - File 1 contents and x1 = 'Description' + x

Comment: File 1 
Title1
Title 2
Title 3

File 2 
Title 11
Descrption..
Description..
END
Title 2
Descrption..
Description..
END

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems including referring to a variable `x1` that hasn't been defined, and defining `count` and `i` variables that aren't used. Trying to get `content_file.next()` won't work, because you already read all the content when you called `content_file.readlines()`.

Instead do something like this: iterate through the content; if a line contains a title then set a flag and write the line to the output file; the flag will be True, and the loop will keep writing lines, until it encounters 'end'.

```
with open('titles', 'r') as titles_file:
    titles = [title.strip().upper() for title in titles_file]

description = False
with open('H:/Python/proj1/p4 faults.swi', 'r') as content, open('outfile.txt') as output:
    for line in content:
        if description:
            output.write(line)
            if line.strip().upper() == "END":
                 description = False
        elif line.strip().upper() in titles:
            output.write(line)
            description = True
```

Comment: Thank for your response. But i couldnt get the answer i needed. I have added the full code above

Comment: I couldn't upload the code due to some problems. But i used your flag method and got the results I wanted. Thanks a ton!